# How to programmatically set permissions for a custom content type created in a module?

Tags: users

I have a module which creates a node type as part of hook_install. I want to be able to automatically set permission to authenticated users to create nodes.

I have tried the following code:

```
 /**
  * Implements hook_enable().
  */
function my_module_enable() {
  $permissions = array('create my_module_content_type content');
  user_role_grant_permissions(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID, $permissions);
}
```

But I receive this error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: create my_module_content_type content in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3111 of ...
```

If I delete the two lines of code, the module installs fine. And when I run those 2 lines of code in an "execute PHP" window after install, they work as desired.

I believe hook_install should execute before hook_enable so the content type should exist when hook_enable is run. Are permissions defined later? Thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: Make sure you have defined this permission in a hook_permission (or hook_perm for Drupal 6) as well.

Comment: Ah, I didn't make clear. My module's hook_install creates "my_module_content_type". As part of that, I think the content module automatically creates the permission. (The two lines of code do run fine if I run them manually after the module is enabled.)

Comment: For which version of drupal is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `user_permission_get_modules` function fails to get the permissions at the point of install (too early in the process, not all the caches have been reset). So you would have to copy the `user_role_grant_permissions` function to your new module, it should look something like this:

```
/**
 * Custom user_role_grant_permissions function
 * does the same thing as user_role_grant_permissions
 * but it can run at install time
 * @see user_role_grant_permissions
 * @param int $rid
 * @param array $permissions
 */
function _my_module_grant_permissions($rid, array $permissions = array()) {
    // this line doesn't work on install / enable hooks
    // $modules = user_permission_get_modules();
    // Grant new permissions for the role.
    foreach ($permissions as $module => $permission_list) {
    foreach ($permission_list as $name) {
        db_merge('role_permission')
        ->key(array(
            'rid' => $rid,
            'permission' => $name,
        ))
        ->fields(array(
            'module' => $module,
        ))
        ->execute();
    }
    }

    // Clear the user access cache.
    drupal_static_reset('user_access');
    drupal_static_reset('user_role_permissions');
}
```

This is slightly different than the `user_role_grant_permissions` module in that the permissions are keyed to the module, so you call it like this:

```
function my_module_enable(){
    $permissions = array(
        // module key
        'my_module' => array(
           // permissions in the module
           'do module things',
           'modify module things',
        ),
    );
    _my_module_grant_permissions(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID, $permissions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all functions are available in the install file.

You will need to look at the code user_role_grant_permissions and probably copy the database statement into your hook_enable, also remember to remove it in hook_disable